# ¿Cómo generar una lista a partir de mi salida?

Tags: python, lista

Quiero crear una lista a partir de mis resultados, comparto una parte de mi código para que se pueda analizar lo que estoy haciendo. Binarizo la imagen y a partir de esa imagen genero los contornos, y encuentro el área de cada uno de los contornos, y esa área se me imprime en mi consola. Tales resultados quiero que se coloquen dentro de la lista.  Abajo adjunto imagen de como me aparece el resultado en mi consola:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('radio.jpg',0)
img = cv2.resize(image,(600,300))
m=((30*ResFinal)/100)
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,m,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
for c in contours:
   area = cv2.contourArea(c)
   if area > 1000 and area < 10000:
       cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
       print('El área es:',area)
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000 and area < 10000:
       (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
       cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow('contornos', img)
cv2.imshow('umbral', th1)
cv2.waitKey(0)        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: La imagen adjunta muestra mi salida de resultados.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añadir elementos a una lista se hace con `lista.append()`. Bastará por tanto que tu programa cree una lista vacía al arrancar y use `.append()` para ir añadiendo cada área a medida que la calcula. Es decir:

```
# Parte inicial omitida...
lista = []
for c in contours:
   area = cv2.contourArea(c)
   if area > 1000 and area < 10000:
       cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
       print('El área es:',area)
       lista.append(area)              # <---- Aqui se añade
# Resto omitido...
```

Ahora bien, la verdadera pregunta es ¿qué quieres hacer con esa lista al final? Tal como está el código los valores se van añadiendo a esa lista, pero después no se hace nada con ella por lo que es como si no lo hubiéramos hecho.

Entiendo que una vez hayas salido del bucle en el que se han analizado todas las imágenes querrás hacer algo con la lista de áreas que has ido acumulando. Por ejemplo podrías imprimir todas las áreas al final del script:

```
print("Areas encontradas:", lista)
```

o quizás quieras calcular algunas estadísticas, como el área promedio:

```
print("Área promedio=", sum(lista)/len(lista))
```

¿O guardarlas en disco en un archivo tipo CSV? ¿o JSON? ¿O en un pickle para que otro programa Python diferente pueda recuperarlas de ahí y hacer otra cosa con ellas?

Comment: Gracias Abulafia, de gran ayuda el código que me compartiste. En efecto, creo que intentaré el guardar el archivo con tipo CVS o JSON. Lo que debo hacer es guardar esa lista, ordenarla de mayor a menor y eliminar las 3 áreas más pequeñas (las 3 últimas) y continuar trabajando con esos valores.

Comment: `resultado = sorted(lista, reverse=True)[0:-3]` hace en una operación lo que necesitas. Ordena la lista (de mayor a menor por el `reverse`) y del resultado ordenado toma todos los elementos del 0 hasta el tercero desde el final. Osea, todos menos los tres últimos.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, estaba revisando acerca de como guardar el archivo CSV y si me lo guarda como un archivo Excel pero no me deja abrirlo al mismo tiempo en el mismo código. Sabes alguna forma de como puedo guardar esos datos y seguirlos usando a lo largo de ese mismo código? o mas bien seria guardar cada uno de los resultados como una variable distinta.

Comment: No veo por qué no vas a poder seguir usándolos después de guardarlos. No es necesario que abras el archivo de nuevo (si no te deja abrirlo de nuevo posiblemente sea porque olvidaste cerrarlo, pero como digo ni siquiera necesitas volver a abrirlo). Simplemente en la lista original aún tienes los datos que puedes seguir usando para otra cosa.

Comment: Es correcto, ya veo y lo comprobé de hecho. Gracias, eres muy amable y un genio en programación. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: No problem :-) Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada entonces para dar por cerrada la pregunta.

Comment: Claro que si :)

Answer (score 2):

Este es un ejemplo de lo que podrías hacer:

```py
contour_areas = []
for c in contours:
   area = cv2.contourArea(c)
   if area > 1000 and area < 10000:
       cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
       contour_areas.append(area)
       print('El área es:', area)
```

Estos serían los pasos a seguir:

1. Crear la variable `contour_areas` (por ejemplo), a la que le asignas una lista vacía. (`contour_areas = []`)
2. En cada iteración del bucle, añadir el área a la lista que se ha creado (`contour_areas.append(area)`)

Nótese que el área se añade dentro de la verificación `if area > 1000 and area < 10000`. En caso de que se quieran añadir todas las áreas, el ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```py
contour_areas = []
for c in contours:
   area = cv2.contourArea(c)
   contour_areas.append(area)
   if area > 1000 and area < 10000:
       cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
       print('El área es:', area)
```